# Run all the unit test cases from npm run test

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

In my React front end project, jest library is used for unit test cases.
I am trying to run the front-end unit test cases from build pipeline.
To do that, I am planning to add a new task in the task group.
The task

```
npm run test
```

executes the unit test cases which are related to the recent changes.
When I run the same command from the VS Code terminal, it is asking to press "a" to run all the test cases.
Even if I run the below command with "--watchAll"

```
npm run test --watchAll
```

*No tests found related to files changed since last commit.
Press `a` to run all tests, or run Jest with `--watchAll`.
*

But I am planning to run all the test cases every time the pipeline is being executed.
What would be the command to achieve that?

I tried goggling for the solution but not found anything concrete.

Comment: The `npm run test` script should run all the test cases, can you show the `jest.config.js`? And check the [`testMatch`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testmatch-arraystring) configuration. Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks @LinDu.
There is no jest.config.js. I have three files with the name *_test.js 
In my  package.json file, 
"scripts": section has the below:
 "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",

Answer (score 1):

The default of `jest` command is run all tests, but looks like your test files are not following the convention:

Jest will look for test files with any of the following popular naming conventions:

- Files with .js suffix in `__tests__` folders.
- Files with .test.js suffix.
- Files with .spec.js suffix.

Checkout [CRA documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/) for more detail